# mkdir failing to create directory in perl

Tags: perl

i think the script previously given was confusing ,this is the script i want to run now, which is not creating directory, please help me in this.

I don't mynd if the code is idiotic , as I am just a beginner in perl. Could you suggest me the right approach for this script, and if I have any errors?

The `output_folder1.txt` contains `10010`, and `output_folder.txt_2` contains `30001`.

I am getting output file cannot be created.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;


print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

my(@folder_name,$temp1,$temp2);

open ONE,"<","/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output_folder_1.txt" || die "Cannot open the file";
@folder_name=<ONE>;
close ONE;

open TWO,"<","/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output_folder_2.txt" || die  "Cannot open the file";
push(@folder_name,<TWO>);
close TWO;


print $folder_name[0],"\n",$folder_name[1],"\n";

$temp1 = pop(@folder_name);
$temp2 = pop(@folder_name);



if($temp1 < 30050)
{

    mkdir "/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output/$temp2/$temp1",0777 or die "File cannot be created";
}
```

Comment: Crosspost http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=941302

Comment: as a side note: you might want to `chomp` your input lines, to avoid unexpected results...

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `$!` to your die string (`die "File cannot be created: $!"`). That'll give you the reason why. `$!` is the error message from the operating system. See ["Error Variables" in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables).

It seems quite possible you're trying to mkdir two directories at once (`…/$temp2` and `…/$temp2/$temp1`). You need two mkdir calls for that, or use [`File::Path`](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm)'s `make_path`.

Answer (score 3):

You should first check if `$temp2` directory exists:

```
unless ( -d "/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output/$temp2" ) {
    mkdir "/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output/$temp2",0777 or die $!;
}
mkdir "/var/www/html/piRNA_html/UNAFold/output/$temp2/$temp1",0777 or die $!;
```

Answer (score 2):

[File::Path::make_path](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aPath) in conjunction with [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Path%3a%3aClass) (or on its own, if you don't care about the nice interface to platform independent paths) should take most of the pain away.